# How to edit this mssql query?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I've got this query below associated with my clan ranking php script.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
  IDNum, 
  IDName, 
  Nation, 
  (SELECT SUM(LoyaltyPoint) 
   FROM USERDATA 
   WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum 
     AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) as ClanLoyalty 
FROM KNIGHTS 
ORDER BY ClanLoyalty DESC
```

I want to add second rule for `MannerPoint` as additional to the Loyalty.
So, it will display both Manner and Loyalty points and order them by both.

For example if clan has 10000 Loyalty and 100 Manner, it will be higher in rankings than 20000 Loyalty and only 50 Manner.

I tried a few but failed. It will be really appreciated if someone is willing to help me.

EDIT: I tried that:
`SELECT TOP 100 IDNum, IDName, Nation, (SELECT SUM(LoyaltyPoint) FROM USERDATA WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) as ClanLoyalty, (SELECT SUM(MannerPoint) FROM USERDATA WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2))) as MannerPoint FROM KNIGHTS ORDER BY ClanLoyalty DESC, MannerPoint DESC`

but it doesnt display at all.

Comment: for starters you need to specify where the Manner points are stored

Comment: They are in USERDATA same as Loyalty points.

Comment: in your main select statement, add another return column for the Manner point and include it in your order by.for e.g 
Select [existingColumn], (select manner) as MannerPoint
from ...
where ...
order by MannerPoint desc, ClanLoyalty DESC

Comment: `SELECT TOP 100 IDNum, IDName, Nation, (SELECT SUM(LoyaltyPoint) FROM USERDATA WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) as ClanLoyalty, (SELECT SUM(MannerPoint) FROM FROM USERDATA WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2))) as MannerPoint FROM KNIGHTS ORDER BY ClanLoyalty DESC, MannerPoint DESC` Like that ? Is that fully correct ?

Comment: yeah like that is correct

Comment: Is it for sure secured and correct ? It doesnt display.

Comment: Also I want both to be considered so it should be in the end `ClanLoyalty DESC AND MannerPoint DESC`

Answer (score 0):

You can sum both `LoyaltyPoint` and `MannerPoint` using outer apply:

```
select top 100
    k.IDNum, 
    k.IDName, 
    k.Nation, 
    u.ClanLoyalty,
    u.ClanManner 
from KNIGHTS as k
    outer apply (
        select
            sum(u.LoyaltyPoint) as ClanLoyalty,
            sum(u.MannerPoint) as ClanManner
        from USERDATA as u
        where u.Knights = k.IDNum and u.Authority in (1, 2)
    ) as u
order by u.ClanManner desc, u.ClanLoyalty desc
```

or simple subquery:

```
select top 100
    k.IDNum, 
    k.IDName, 
    k.Nation, 
    u.ClanLoyalty,
    u.ClanManner
from KNIGHTS as k
    left outer join (
        select
            u.Knights,
            sum(u.LoyaltyPoint) as ClanLoyalty,
            sum(u.MannerPoint) as ClanManner
        from USERDATA as u
        where u.Authority in (1, 2)
        group by u.Knights
    ) as u on u.Knights = k.IDNum
order by u.ClanManner desc, u.ClanLoyalty desc
```

Don't know how do you want to order your records, if you want to order by sum of ClanManner and ClanLoyalty, you can do this:

```
order by isnull(u.ClanManner, 0) + isnull(u.ClanLoyalty, 0) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
IDNum, IDName, Nation, 
    (SELECT SUM(LoyaltyPoint)
     FROM USERDATA 
     WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum 
           AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) as ClanLoyalty,
    (SELECT SUM(MannerPoint) 
     FROM USERDATA 
     WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum 
           AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2))) as MannerPoint 
FROM KNIGHTS 
ORDER BY ClanLoyalty DESC, MannerPoint DESC`
```

has a syntax issue with an extra parenthesis in it and should be:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
IDNum, IDName, Nation, 
    (SELECT SUM(LoyaltyPoint)
     FROM USERDATA 
     WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum 
           AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) as ClanLoyalty,
    (SELECT SUM(MannerPoint) 
     FROM USERDATA 
     WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum 
           AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2) ) as MannerPoint 
FROM KNIGHTS 
ORDER BY ClanLoyalty DESC, MannerPoint DESC`
```