# Query does not return anything?

Tags: sql-server

This query display correctly in my clan php ranking script.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
  IDNum, 
  IDName, 
  Nation, 
  (SELECT SUM(LoyaltyPoint) 
   FROM USERDATA 
   WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum 
     AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) as ClanLoyalty 
FROM KNIGHTS 
ORDER BY ClanLoyalty DESC
```

but I wanted to add on top of `LoyaltyPoint` second rule for `MannerPoint`.

```
SELECT TOP 100
  IDNum,
  IDName,
  Nation,
  (SELECT SUM(LoyaltyPoint)
    FROM USERDATA
    WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum
        AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) as ClanLoyalty,
  (SELECT SUM(MannerPoint) 
   FROM USERDATA
   WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum
       AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) ) as MannerPoint
FROM KNIGHTS
ORDER BY ClanLoyalty DESC, MannerPoint DESC
```

but this doesn't work and doesn't display.

I use MSSQL 2005

Comment: you should provide a testcase, also this has absolutely nothing to do with php?

Comment: There is something wrong with the query thats what it causes to dont work. Can you please see it and let me know if its appearing to be fine ?

Comment: Don't post **the same** question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695518/how-to-edit-this-mssql-query again

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra parenthesis here;

```
AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) ) as MannerPoint
```

Adjusted code with extra parenthesis removed:

```
AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2) ) as MannerPoint
```

Comment: so how to make it correct ?

Comment: @nRov - added the simple corrected line

Comment: `SELECT TOP 100
  IDNum,
  IDName,
  Nation,
  (SELECT SUM(LoyaltyPoint)
    FROM USERDATA
    WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum
        AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) as ClanLoyalty,
  (SELECT SUM(MannerPoint) 
   FROM USERDATA
   WHERE USERDATA.Knights = KNIGHTS.IDNum
       AND USERDATA.Authority IN(1, 2)) as MannerPoint
FROM KNIGHTS
ORDER BY ClanLoyalty DESC, MannerPoint DESC` and it works. Woot. but is it secure and well structured query or not ? Like my default one with loyalty only ?